# Akka.net - Streams with parallelism, backpressure and ActorRef

Tags: akka-stream, akka.net

Tying to learn how use Akka.net Streams to process items in parallel from a Source.Queue, with the processing done in an Actor.

I've been able to get it to work with calling a function with Sink.ForEachParallel, and it works as expected.

Is it possible to process items in parallel with Sink.ActorRefWithAck (as I would prefer it utilize back-pressure)?

Answer (score 2):

About to press Post, when tried to combine previous attempts and viola!

Previous attempts with ForEachParallel failed when I tried to create the actor within, but couldn't do so in an async function. If I use an single actor previous declared, then the Tell would work, but I couldn't get the parallelism I desired.

I got it to work with a router with roundrobin configuration.

```
var props = new RoundRobinPool(5).Props(Props.Create<MyActor>());
var actor = Context.ActorOf(props);

flow = Source.Queue<Element>(2000,OverflowStrategy.Backpressure)            
.Select(x => {
 return new Wrapper() { Element = x, Request = ++cnt };
})
.To(Sink.ForEachParallel<Wrapper>(5, (s) => { actor.Tell(s); }))
.Run(materializer);
```

The Request ++cnt is for console output to verify the requests are being processed as desired.

MyActor has a long delay on every 10th request to verify the backpressure was working.

Comment: This doesn't do backpressure, as ultimately you're sending messages using `actor.Tell`, which doesn't backpressure - messages will just start to pile up on actor's mailbox. If you want to actually backpressure, you can change ForEachParallel with `.SelectAsync(5, s => actor.Ask<Ack>(s, timeout)).To(Sink.Ignore<Ack>())` and make actors send back the Ack message to backpressure.

Comment: Thanks for the info -- maybe b/c my actor was a roundrobin I thought it was doing what I wanted.